# second ssh session can not connect to docker host

Tags: ssh, docker, debian

I have server with debian operating system. I installed docker on it and it works fine, as you can see as follow:

```
root@3053b0461a3c:/# which wget
/usr/bin/wget
root@3053b0461a3c:/#
```

An ubuntu based container is running.
Then I started a second terminal, connect via ssh to server and type in console

```
docker ps
```

But as output I've got the message:

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
```

Why the docker service is not running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unset the environment variable `DOCKER_HOST` and it should work.

https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/eff810aed688879f67a3730c41d9adce4637470f/docs/installation/ubuntulinux.md

Try `unset DOCKER_HOST`

In most unix-based (or -like) environments that I've seen there is the concept of environment variables, which can be considered as dynamic configuration. The 2 functions available are:

- `set` which sets to an environment variable a special value
- `unset` which removes an environment variable.

On the case of `DOCKER_HOST`, docker uses this variable to know whether it should attach to a network host, e.g. `tcp://192.137.23.11` or to a local Unix socket.

Comment: How can I do that on debian?

Comment: Fist of all, thanks so much for your answer. Can you please explain what that means unset DOCKER_HOST?